# Running dual Adafruit GPS at 10Hz on a Teensy 3.2

Tags: gps, teensy, tinygps

Excuse the crudity of this question but I'm having quite the trouble trying to run the two **Adafruit Ultimate GPS v3** modules at **10Hz** on the **Teensy 3.2 board**. The modules are connected over the hardware serial ports 1 and 3. There is also an **IMU (MPU6050)** connected over the I2C interface.

> ### Aim:
>
> -To determine the difference between the course over ground and the body attitude (yaw) of a vehicle
>
> ### Issues:
>
> -By default, the GPS modules only run at 1Hz and at 9600 baud. I'm sending the required PMTK commands over their respective serial ports
>   1 and 3 to increase those to 10Hz and 115200 baud. I'm using hardware
>   serial because the SoftwareSerial library was messing up the
>   interrupts for the I2C interface and wasn't reliable at the baud rate
>   required for 10Hz.
>
> -When using the TinyGPS++ library, it seems that the received chars for the GPS 1 and 2 modules were the same, which led me to believe
>   that it wasn't behaving correctly, and I was getting no fixes. Since I
>   also need to run a Kalman filter for each GPS module at 10Hz (which
>   might not work at that speed on the Teensy), I switched to the NeoGPS
>   library, which I'm told, requires much less system resources and is
>   much faster.
>
> -The NeoGPS library also does not return any successful fix messages due to possibly being misconfigured (I'm using the default
>   configuration files)
>
> Below is the code I'm using with the TinyGPS++ library (sans the IMU
>   parts)
>
> With this, I'm only getting stars (*), and the same number of received
>   characters for both GPS 1 and 2, hence my assumption that it is
>   faulty;

```
#include <TinyGPS++.h>

    static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 115200;

    // The TinyGPS++ object
    TinyGPSPlus gps;

    void setup()
    {
      // The serial connection to the GPS device
      #define GPS_1_Serial Serial1
      #define GPS_2_Serial Serial3
      GPS_1_Serial.begin(9600);
      GPS_1_Serial.write("$PMTK220,100*2F\r\n");
     //switch the GPS baud rate to 115200
      GPS_1_Serial.write("$PMTK251,115200*27\r\n");
     //change baud rate of serial port to 38400
      GPS_1_Serial.flush();
      delay(10);
      GPS_1_Serial.end();

      GPS_2_Serial.begin(9600);
      GPS_2_Serial.write("$PMTK220,100*2F\r\n");
     //switch the GPS baud rate to 115200
      GPS_2_Serial.write("$PMTK251,115200*27\r\n");
     //change baud rate of serial port to 38400
      GPS_2_Serial.flush();
      delay(10);
      GPS_2_Serial.end();

      Serial.begin(115200);

      while (!Serial);
      Serial.println(TinyGPSPlus::libraryVersion());
      Serial.println();
      Serial.println(F("   Fix  Date       Time     Date    Course Speed Card  Chars Sentences Checksum"));
      Serial.println(F("   Age                      Age     --- from GPS ----  RX    RX        Fail"));
      Serial.println(F("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));


    }

    void loop()
    {
      static const double LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;
    //GPS________________________________________________________GPS_1___________________________________________________________________
      GPS_1_Serial.begin(GPSBaud);
      Serial.println("Listening to GPS_1");

      printDateTime(gps.date, gps.time);

      printFloat(gps.course.deg(), gps.course.isValid(), 7, 2);
      printFloat(gps.speed.kmph(), gps.speed.isValid(), 6, 2);
      printStr(gps.course.isValid() ? TinyGPSPlus::cardinal(gps.course.deg()) : "*** ", 6);



      printInt(gps.charsProcessed(), true, 6);
      printInt(gps.sentencesWithFix(), true, 10);
      printInt(gps.failedChecksum(), true, 9);
      Serial.println();



      if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
        Serial.println(F("No GPS data received: check wiring"));
      smartDelay(100);
      GPS_1_Serial.end();
    // ---------------------------------GPS_2----------------------------


      GPS_2_Serial.begin(GPSBaud);

      Serial.println("Listening to GPS_2");

      printDateTime1(gps.date, gps.time);

      printFloat1(gps.course.deg(), gps.course.isValid(), 7, 2);
      printFloat1(gps.speed.kmph(), gps.speed.isValid(), 6, 2);
      printStr1(gps.course.isValid() ? TinyGPSPlus::cardinal(gps.course.deg()) : "*** ", 6);



      printInt1(gps.charsProcessed(), true, 6);
      printInt1(gps.sentencesWithFix(), true, 10);
      printInt1(gps.failedChecksum(), true, 9);
      Serial.println();



      if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
        Serial.println(F("No GPS data received: check wiring"));

      smartDelay1(100);
      GPS_2_Serial.end();


    }

    // This custom version of delay() ensures that the gps object
    // is being "fed".
    static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)
    {
      unsigned long start = millis();
      do 
      {
        while (GPS_1_Serial.available())
          gps.encode(GPS_1_Serial.read());
      } while (millis() - start < ms);
    }

    static void smartDelay1(unsigned long ms)
    {
      unsigned long start = millis();
      do
      {
        while (GPS_2_Serial.available())
          gps.encode(GPS_2_Serial.read());

      } while (millis() - start < ms);
    }

    static void printFloat(float val, bool valid, int len, int prec)
    {
      if (!valid)
      {
        while (len-- > 1)
          Serial.print('*');
        Serial.print(' ');
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print(val, prec);
        int vi = abs((int)val);
        int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
        flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
        for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
          Serial.print(' ');
      }
      smartDelay(0);
    }

    static void printFloat1(float val, bool valid, int len, int prec)
    {
      if (!valid)
      {
        while (len-- > 1)
          Serial.print('*');
        Serial.print(' ');
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.print(val, prec);
        int vi = abs((int)val);
        int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
        flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
        for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
          Serial.print(' ');
      }
      smartDelay1(0);
    }

    static void printInt(unsigned long val, bool valid, int len)
    {
      char sz[32] = "*****************";
      if (valid)
        sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
      sz[len] = 0;
      for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
        sz[i] = ' ';
      if (len > 0) 
        sz[len-1] = ' ';
      Serial.print(sz);
      smartDelay(0);
    }

    static void printInt1(unsigned long val, bool valid, int len)
    {
      char sz[32] = "*****************";
      if (valid)
        sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
      sz[len] = 0;
      for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
        sz[i] = ' ';
      if (len > 0) 
        sz[len-1] = ' ';
      Serial.print(sz);
      smartDelay1(0);
    }

    static void printDateTime(TinyGPSDate &d, TinyGPSTime &t)
    {
      if (!d.isValid())
      {
        Serial.print(F("********** "));
      }
      else
      {
        char sz[32];
        sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d ", d.month(), d.day(), d.year());
        Serial.print(sz);
      }

      if (!t.isValid())
      {
        Serial.print(F("******** "));
      }
      else
      {
        char sz[32];
        sprintf(sz, "%02d:%02d:%02d ", t.hour(), t.minute(), t.second());
        Serial.print(sz);
      }

      printInt(d.age(), d.isValid(), 5);
      smartDelay(0);
    }

    static void printDateTime1(TinyGPSDate &d, TinyGPSTime &t)
    {
      if (!d.isValid())
      {
        Serial.print(F("********** "));
      }
      else
      {
        char sz[32];
        sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d ", d.month(), d.day(), d.year());
        Serial.print(sz);
      }

      if (!t.isValid())
      {
        Serial.print(F("******** "));
      }
      else
      {
        char sz[32];
        sprintf(sz, "%02d:%02d:%02d ", t.hour(), t.minute(), t.second());
        Serial.print(sz);
      }

      printInt(d.age(), d.isValid(), 5);
      smartDelay1(0);
    }


    static void printStr(const char *str, int len)
    {
      int slen = strlen(str);
      for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
        Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
      smartDelay(0);
    }

    static void printStr1(const char *str, int len)
    {
      int slen = strlen(str);
      for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
        Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
      smartDelay1(0);
    }
```

> This is the NeoGPS library version I've attempted, which does not
>   output any indication that it is working successfully;

```
#include <NMEAGPS.h>

static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 115200;

// NMEAGPS object
NMEAGPS gps;


void setup()
{

  // The serial connection to the GPS device
  #define GPS_1_Serial Serial1
  #define GPS_2_Serial Serial3
  GPS_1_Serial.begin(9600);
  GPS_1_Serial.write("$PMTK220,100*2F\r\n");
 //switch the GPS baud rate to 115200
  GPS_1_Serial.write("$PMTK251,115200*27\r\n");
 //change baud rate of serial port to 38400
  GPS_1_Serial.flush();
  delay(10);
  GPS_1_Serial.end();
  GPS_1_Serial.begin(GPSBaud);



  GPS_2_Serial.begin(9600);
  GPS_2_Serial.write("$PMTK220,100*2F\r\n");
 //switch the GPS baud rate to 115200
  GPS_2_Serial.write("$PMTK251,115200*27\r\n");
 //change baud rate of serial port to 38400
  GPS_2_Serial.flush();
  delay(10);
  GPS_2_Serial.end();
  GPS_2_Serial.begin(GPSBaud);


  Serial.begin(115200);

  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println();
  //Serial.println(F("  Time     Date    Course Speed Card  Chars Sentences Checksum"));
  //Serial.println(F(""));
  Serial.println(F("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));


}

void loop()
{

//GPS________________________________________________________GPS_1___________________________________________________________________

  Serial.println("Listening to GPS_1");
  while (gps.available(GPS_1_Serial)) {
    gps_fix fix_1 = gps.read();
    if (fix_1.valid.location){
      Serial.println("Successful Location");
    }
    if (fix_1.valid.time) {
      Serial.println("Successful Time");

    }
  }

  Serial.println();


// ---------------------------------GPS_2----------------------------

  Serial.println("Listening to GPS_2");
  while (gps.available(GPS_2_Serial)) {
    gps_fix fix_2 = gps.read();
    if (fix_2.valid.location){
      Serial.println("Successful Location");
    }
    if (fix_2.valid.time) {
      Serial.println("Successful Time");

    }
  }

}
```

I'm still a beginner when it comes to programming with an Arduino, and I appreciate any assistance to get on the right track.

Thank you for reading

Yours faithfully,

Cem Huray

Comment: were you successful in running one gps module?

Comment: why are you switching the baud rate?

Comment: I was able to run both modules at 1Hz at 9600 baud, I need to change the baud rate to ensure that there is no data loss at 10Hz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need two instances of the parser, too:

```
NMEAGPS gps_1, gps_2;

       ...

//___________________GPS_1______________________

  //Serial.println("Listening to GPS_1");  <-- don't print too much!
  while (gps_1.available(GPS_1_Serial)) {
    gps_fix fix_1 = gps_1.read();
          ...

//___________________GPS_2______________________

  //Serial.println("Listening to GPS_2");  <-- don't print too much!
  while (gps_2.available(GPS_2_Serial)) {
    gps_fix fix_2 = gps_2.read();
          ...
```

Also answered on the Arduino forum [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=548264.msg3738878#msg3738878).

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, sorry I couldn't reply, I'm trying to smooth some stuff out, but brilliant library I must say

Comment: @C.Huray, Thanks!  If this solves your problem, click on the green triangle next to my answer to "accept" it.  Otherwise, your question lingers on, haunting us forever.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

What is processing_style in NMEAGPS ? My understanding is there is a PS_POLLING style that may not work well with two GPSes and PS_INTERRUPT, that I'm not sure can handle Teensy well.

Have you tried to read directly from the Serial without any library ? When it's working, you can try to plug the library back (or parse the strings from GPS, which is quite easy).

Comment: No problem for the NeoGPS INTERRUPT processing style: just make sure the separate ISRs call the separate `gps1.handle(c)` or `gps2.handle(c)`.